# Python Selenium Error Message - module has no element Chrome()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I built a web scraping tool in Python 3.6 that utilizes Selenium with the Chrome Webdriver. I have been using the script for weeks with no issues. I got a new laptop last week, and now my script is having issues. The chromedriver is in a file in my downloads file - but I point to the path.

Relevant Code Pieces:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/*****/Downloads/Install Files/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe")
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ipython-input-16-6bf54a05a8d5", line 1, in module
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/******/Downloads/Install 
Files/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe")

AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

I checked the selenium file and it doesn't have a "Chrome" folder, just "Firefox" and "Remote". I get the same error when I try to run webdriver.Firefox().

I am running Python with the Spyder IDE in the Anaconda 3 Package. Selenium was installed with pip. I have Selenium version 3.4.3 and chromedriver version 2.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works for me, try uninstalling your selenium package 'pip uninstall selenium' and install it back

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to what my issue ended up being. I tried it in IDLE and it worked. I had installed via pip and it wasn't attached to the Anaconda version of python. I used the anaconda console and installed with conda. So it's up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my selenium folder and there was only a webdriver folder there with firefox and something else. Essentially it was empty. This was on a shared driver.

I had installed selenium on my PC on an earlier date. I copied the version from my PC to the share and tried again and it worked.

It looks like the pip Selenium install doesn't always do a complete install. If you have this problem try installing it to different locations, different drives, directories and see what happens. Good luck. Selenium works, but you are missing files.